# logging in daemon process

Tags: linux, logging, daemon

I'm new to all this stuff, so please forgive if a question is stupid. I'm running a script as daemon, in order to debug it I'm trying to dump logs in file, but no file is created. And if I run script not as daemon log file is created and logs are dumped. What's wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. I'm running centos

Comment: How are you running it as a daemon? And how are you logging to a file? What language is this script in? Is it a bash/shell script? Or python or perl etc.?

Answer (score 2):

What do you use in your script to create log files? If the script is too large to show it here, put it to pastebin.com or such.

To write messages to syslog from a shell script, use `logger`, the results can be found in /var/log/syslog (or elsewhere when you want it).